# something about the reproducibility of pytorch on multi-GPU

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, gpu, multi-gpu

I've set the random seed to make my model reproducible and it works when I use a single GPU to train my model.
But it doesn't seem to work when I tried to use nn.DataParallel() to train my model on two GPUs. The result is different every time.
So where is the problem?
the function of setting seed is like this:

```
def set_seed(seed):
    random.seed(seed)
    np.random.seed(seed)
    torch.manual_seed(seed)
    torch.cuda.manual_seed(seed)
    torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(seed)
    torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = False
    torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True
```

Comment: Have you set [`torch.use_deterministic_algorithms()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.use_deterministic_algorithms.html#torch.use_deterministic_algorithms)?

Comment: I tried, but it raised an error:RuntimeError: Deterministic behavior was enabled with either `torch.use_deterministic_algorithms(True)` or `at::Context::setDeterministicAlgorithms(true)`, but this operation is not deterministic because it uses CuBLAS and you have CUDA >= 10.2. To enable deterministic behavior in this case, you must set an environment variable before running your PyTorch application: CUBLAS_WORKSPACE_CONFIG=:4096:8 or CUBLAS_WORKSPACE_CONFIG=:16:8. For more information, go to https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#cublasApi_reproducibility

Comment: Then one or more of the operations you are performing in your code is non deterministic. You should be able to determine which one it is by looking at the stack trace for that error. Once you figure it out you'll need to replace it with an alternative that is deterministic. Keep in mind that's only the first non deterministic operation. There may be more. You'll need to repeat this process untill you don't use any nondeterministic algorithms.

Comment: thanks for your answering.I have added the "CUBLAS_WORKSPACE_CONFIG=:4096:8" and :CUBLAS_WORKSPACE_CONFIG=:16:8" to my environment variable. My code can run now.However, it's still irreproducible on multi-GPU